# cakephp array results [maximum depth reached]

Tags: cakephp

i have two models. **Teacher** and **Subject** joined by **HABTM** defined both ways. A teacher can teach many subjects and a subject can be taught by many teachers.my **join table** is **subjects_teachers** and have fields **id,teacher_id and subject_id.**

Fetching Teacher data from its model, i expect all teachers and their respective subjects ,
Fetching Subject data from its model i expect to also see the teachers teaching that particular subject

**problem**
 on both instances, the associated model returns the correct number of records but the data is absent. i see **[maximum depth reached]** when i display the respective arrays.

I **removed the id field** from the **join table** and that **fixed only the Teacher model**.The Subject model still has the problem.

i just need to know what [maximum depth reached] means and **why removing the id filed from the join table fixed the Teacher problem but not Subject**.

also if its important i should mention that my Teacher model **primary key field doesnt follow convention**
**SUBJECT model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Teacher' => array(
    'className' => 'Teacher',
    'joinTable' => 'subjects_teachers',
    'foreignKey' => 'subject_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'teacher_id',
    'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    )
);
```

**Teacher Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Subject' => array(
    'className' => 'Subject',
    'joinTable' => 'subjects_teachers',
    'foreignKey' => 'teacher_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'subject_id',
    'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    )
);
```

**Results from subject**

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Subject' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'subject_code' => '121',
        'subject_name' => 'Mathematics',
        'compulsory' => true
    ),
    'Teacher' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        )
    )
),
```

**Results from Teacher before removin id field**

```
array(
'Teacher' => array(
    'teacher_id' => '6',
    'first_name' => 'George',
   ),
  'Subject' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'subject_code' => '121',
        'subject_name' => 'Mathematics',
        'compulsory' => true,
        'SubjectsTeacher' => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        )
    )
```

**Results after removing id field**

```
'Subject' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'subject_code' => '121',
        'subject_name' => 'Mathematics',
        'compulsory' => true
    ),
```

Comment: Can you post your model definitions exactly?

From your last line ("also if its important i should mention that my Teacher model primary key field doesnt follow convention") I can deduce that the problem is related to CakePHP automagic relations not working because of not following the convention. There are ways to avoid that specifying yourself which columns are used as foreing keys. But this is just a deduction. Need the requested code to confirm it

Comment: i get your point..so what does this maximum depth reached mean because obviously cakephp identifies all the related records but just cant desplay them

Answer (score 4):

Your data exists, the debugger just wont display it because the `depth` option limits it. Use `debug()` (default depth = `25`) or `Debugger::dump()/exportVar()` with a depth (second argument, defaults to `3`) high enough for your deeply nested data.

See also

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html**
- **http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Debugger.html**

Answer (score 0):

It is related to model attribute recursive

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive